# get resource filename/URI from resource ID

Tags: android

I'm trying to save a local resource, an image, to the SD card. But i cant figure out how to get the filename from the resource, i can create a Bitmap and save it to the SD-card but cant seem to find the filename! I've got a bunch of files named pic001.png-pic100.png and want the corresponding file on the card to be named the same.

Comment: can you paste your code here? whatever you do up to

Comment: solved it this way: getApplicationContext().getResources().getResourceEntryName(resourceId);